# Check a PHP $_GET variable inside jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway to check a PHP $_GET variable in jQuery?

Here is what i mean:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
$('.updatearea').load('main.php<?=$url?> .updatearea');
}, 5000);
```

I only wanna execute the code above IF (isset($_GET['phpvariable'])

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

> Is that possible?

Yes, but the more elegant way might be to use PHP to decide whether the code should be output in the first place:

```
 <? if (isset($_GET['phpvariable']): ?>

 var refreshId = setInterval(function()
 {
  $('.updatearea').load('main.php<?=$url?> .updatearea');
 }, 5000);

 <? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do it in JavaScript and not in PHP?

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['phpvariable'])){ ?>
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
$('.updatearea').load('main.php<?=$url?> .updatearea');
}, 5000);
<?php } ?>
```